# How to use the navigate request mode?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

[It is said that this request mode is a special mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode). It’s so special that I was unable to find an example using it and that the code below fire an error in the console.

```
fetch("http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/flashredirect/?https://github.com/git-receive-pack", {mode:"navigate"})
  .then(function(response) {console.log(response);});;
```

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735612/what-is-the-point-of-request-mode-in-the-fetch-api-especially-with-respect-to-c/47736998#47736998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `mode` option takes a value that is from the `Request.mode` interface, not all of the possible `Request.mode` values are allowed for fetch.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode):

> navigate — A mode for supporting navigation. The navigate value is intended to be used only by HTML navigation. A navigate request is created only while navigating between documents.

So to use it, click a regular link in an HTML document or assign a new URL to the `location` global. The browser will set the mode to [navigate](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#navigate) under the hood.

Comment: I know. But I’m looking for a fetch example this is a valid mode for fetch. Sorry for having forgot to put the link in my question.

Comment: @user2284570 — It isn't a valid mode for fetch. I addressed that in the first sentence of this answer! It's just mentioned in the fetch specification because that turned into the general place to describe making HTTP requests from HTML.

Comment: @Quentin Maybe it's useful in service workers or something?

Comment: @Quentin but from https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request navigate is an acceptable mode.

Comment: @user2284570 — Where does it say that? The section you link to just says the input has to be a request.

Comment: @Quentin `A request has an associated mode, which is "same-origin", "cors", "no-cors", "navigate", or "websocket". Unless stated otherwise, it is "no-cors". `

Comment: @user2284570 — Which, *again*, is in a section talking about **all** requests and not just requests initiated with `fetch`. If you scroll up a little bit there is a big table which lists a bunch of different types of requests, including "HTML’s `<iframe>` and `<frame>`"

Comment: Thank you. I know it’s not related but what’s the difference in terms of contents between an `opaque-redirect filtered response` and a `opaque filtered response` ?